# Is there a reason to keep an SVN branch?

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

I created a trunk, branched off my code, completed a feature on the branch, then merged the branch back into the trunk.

Is there a reason I need to keep the branch around?

Thanks

Comment: Even if you delete it, it will still exist. So I would say delete it.

Comment: When you say "delete it" do you mean delete it off my local drive or in the SVN repository?

Comment: I mean in the repository. The branch is still there, you can check out the revision before the delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on whether you made any changes to the trunk after branching off or not. If any changes were made in trunk in parallel to completing a feature, you may want to keep both in case you find a defect or in case you need to roll back/ compare code. If no change was made, you can surely delete the branch.